# How to use spotdl

Tags: python, spotify, document

I am working on spotdl to download song. But I have some problems:

1. I can not get the information of the song, like its artist, genre,..
2. I can not change the output file, like, when I download a mp3 file, I want to set name for it by meself
   How can I do that

I tried read the docs, but can not get it

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77475500/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).